# How to have a github bot accept a lambda request and make a pull request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda, github-actions, github-api

I am was curious to see if I would be able to build a github bot/application that automatically creates pull request when a file is changed. Please let me know if this question does not make sense. I am new college grad just starting my first full time job as a software engineer.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.